# How can you fake an ellipses on a div with multiple nested elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My structure is as follows:

```
<div class="post">
    <p>In neque elit. Semper amet leo. Pulvinar ullamcorper ac nullam convallis amet nunc scelerisque porta. Dolor eu ornare ligula ut voluptatem. Orci dictum ullamcorper elit sit orci. Etiam lectus vel mattis suscipit iure sem imperdiet ante. Sed rutrum potenti magna arcu ullamcorper. Vivamus convallis velit. Eget elit scelerisque tincidunt cras ultrices metus nulla libero et mus luctus. Sagittis orci potenti scelerisque etiam eiusmod tempor pellentesque lobortis rutrum interdum nibh. Tellus quas elit. Pellentesque rhoncus magna. Eleifend in amet. Hac neque est rutrum et dis varius et dui. Vestibulum nulla magna. Magna interdum ac eros bibendum velit. Et amet nunc vel amet vel ligula dictum tristique dolor odio dui. Morbi dolor lectus. Nascetur nullam est.</p>
    <p>Vitae nulla vitae. Pellentesque ullamcorper magna. Non impedit in rhoncus lacus nulla ut vulputate nulla. Eros ultricies leo dolor ut luctus. Maecenas pharetra ut. Metus ut congue. Lacus ut vestibulum. Auctor tortor tempus. Aptent mattis lectus. Condimentum dolore velit maecenas officia arcu velit placerat nullam urna lacus justo. Nunc donec quam neque tortor enim sem eros dui vulputate rhoncus nam. Ut semper ad eu ac vel turpis duis ornare. Euismod mattis ante. Non aliquet eleifend ut mollis eget. Donec placerat at. In porttitor pellentesque. Accumsan sit arcu vestibulum habitant tempor ultrices justo praesent. Dui aliquam mauris in aliquam magna erat quisque orci. Conubia metus proin eu tincidunt wisi bibendum id condimentum in justo dui qui est dapibus. Facilisis eget at.</p>
    <p>Id ac ullamcorper odio urna tortor elit quam elementum. Erat vivamus ut sit massa metus maecenas wisi suspendisse quis hendrerit mauris. Quam at sodales blandit lacus vestibulum. Elit suspendisse quo. Vivamus auctor wisi. Quis id lobortis. Diam sociosqu et elementum erat magna. Elit elit eu. Laoreet habitant tempor pellentesque dictum eget. Ipsum lectus dignissim id elit proin ullamcorper quis morbi.</p>
</div>
```

What I'm looking to do, is set a max-height on `.post` (200px),  and then fake an ellipses when it goes past that point (or overflows). The problem I'm having with jQuery plugins, is that it only works on the individual `<p>` elements, instead of the div as a whole, so I'm ending up with something like this:

```
First Paragraph:
Line one Line one Line one Line one Line one Line one Line one Line one 
Line two Line two Line two Line two Line two Line two Line two ...

Second Paragraph:
Line one Line one Line one Line one Line one Line one Line one Line one 
Line two Line two Line two Line two Line two Line two Line two ...
```

Etc.

I'm all for using jQuery or JavaScript solutions if they'll work, but like I said, most of them only work on the `<p>` element, and not the `<div>` element. :(

This is basically to be used for a blog post preview. I want a sample of the text, but not the entire thing.

JS Fiddle for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/kvh11xhg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it using a pseudo element :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kvh11xhg/3/)**

*CSS :*

```
.post {
    max-height: 6em;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height:1.2em;
    position:relative;
}
.post:after{
    content:"...";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; right:0;
    padding:0 .5em;
    background: #fff;
}
```